# How to pass a string variable as an argument to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to pass a string variable as an argument to a JavaScript function, but I am getting no results on doing it, nothing inside the functions gets executed when a call to a JavaScript function is made.
A little help also is appreciable.

Comment: Please post the javascript code you are trying to execute. Without some sample code it is impossible to identify your problem.

Comment: Posting the relevant code would help to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the function will be like this

declaring and defining function

```
function demo(arg)
{
 //use arg for your code
}
```

calling function

```
demo("hello");
```

hope this helps....

Comment: thanks for huge replies.......but my questions was that i have a  function say myfunction(var) where var is a string variable and the corresponding definition is function myFunction()
{
x=document.getElementById("myid");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML="Hello";}     but i am getting no output......thamks Mahipat singh

Comment: wrap your code in document ready function $(document).ready(function(){your code}).

Comment: but how to make a call to a function say function myfunction(variable)   in document ready function

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(value) {
  alert(value);
}


show('test');
```

If this is not what you're looking for, you should clarify your question.

Comment: thanks sir.......but the question actually look likes function show(var){ displaying the value of the variable "var"}   show(var1) where var1 is a string variable not a value.........thanks Mahipat singh

Comment: So use `alert(var.value);` ?

Comment: actually instead of passing a value "test" in show('test') i want to pass a variable whose value is equal to test, i don't want to pass the value 'test' directly sir

Comment: Alright. That's basically the same. 

`var test = 'Hello!'; show(test);`

Comment: thank you sir for keep in answering......but for the variable test i am assigning the value from the database for the current user.........can you help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you don't need to specify the type of a variable. If your variable is a string, the system will handle it as such. Here is a basic example embedded in an HTML page to get you started:

**Edit**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="myid"></span>
        <script >
            var myVar = "Hello world !";

            displayVar(myVar);

            function displayVar(myParam) {
                x = document.getElementById("myid"); // Find the element
                x.innerHTML = myParam;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok what if i make a call to the function displayvar(myvar) from outside the script element and also myvar is getting a value from the database

Answer (score -1):

you can dump you variable as json format, and then parse json string to variable in your function

```
//this is your params
my_params = 
[
  "dict": {
    "abc":true,
    "xyz":1
  },
  "data": "blah blah blah..."
]

//dump params to json
var myObject = JSON.stringify(my_params);

//pass param to function
my_function( myObject ); 

function my_function( object )
{
    //parse json to object
    myObject = JSON.parse( object );
    alert( myObject ["data"] );
    ...
}
```